Trouble with debugging with "Step Into (CTRL+F11)" on remote kernel in Spyder IDE
I make a remote connection with nanopi using remote spyder kerner. I can successfully run and debug files.
But when I want to step into (Ctrl+F11) function which locate in another file, Spyder Editor DON'T open this file. But debug process still continued (I can see it in "Variable Explorer" and there are no error in "Console").
I have this problem ONLY with remote kernels.
How I can fix it? I want the Editor open the files when I step into functions and see every step of debugging.
I try to find similar issue but i have no result.
I check the versions of packages on my nanopi where i start a remote kernel and on PC where IDE running:
Versions on nanopi:
spyder-kernels 2.5.2
Python 3.10.12

Versions on Linux OS:
spyder-kernels 2.5.2.
Python 3.10.12

